# Character induced by the trivial character of a subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

We know that if $\{ e\}<G$ is the trivial subgroup and $\chi_0$ is the (necessarily) trivial character of $\{e\}$, then the induced character in $G$ can be written neatly as

$$
\textrm{Ind}_{\{ e \}}^{\ G}(\chi_0) = \sum_{\chi}\chi(1)\chi,
$$

where the sum is taken over the irreducible characters of $G$.

But if $H < G$ is any subgroup and $\chi_0$ is the trivial character of $H$, can we find a similarly neat expression for

$$
\textrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\chi_0)?
$$

Comment: You can induce any class function (i.e. invariant by conjugation) according to the first formula on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_character . Replacing $f$ by $ \chi_0 $ should give the result. Of course, it depends what you mean by "similarly neat"...

Comment: You will obtain the permutation representation corresponding to the action of $G$ on $G/H$. See for example section 3.3 in Serre's "Linear representations of finite groups".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then inducing the trivial character $(1_H)^G$ can be interpreted as a transitive permutation character: here $G$ acts by right multiplcation on the right cosets of $H$ in $G$. There is a lot to say about this character and in general it does not split in irreducibles as neatly as *the regular character* $(1_{1})^G$ you mentioned.  There are many boooks in which you can find properties of the permutation character, [I.M. Isaacs, Character Theory of Finite Groups](https://epdf.pub/character-theory-of-finite-groupse2dda579db259807d35b61b215c0d2f434546.html), Chapter 5, being one of them. Another one [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=YVURXmtSmokC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=permutation%20character%20groups&source=bl&ots=8U_8FOOPBP&sig=ACfU3U2kaVT-MqmNfFItMdVs4LYJ7Dsu0A&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ49r765LoAhXP-KQKHXHqC0sQ6AEwGnoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=permutation%20character%20groups&f=false).